# multi dimension json string to object

Tags: java, json

i have JSON string, it maybe not be in correct form. But I need to map it to Java objects: like StockTransaction, StockTransactionDetail, StockTransactionSerial

```
   {
 "STOCK_TRANSACTION": [
  {
   "STOCK_ID" : "1", "DELIVERER_STOCK_ID": "1", "TYPE ":"1", "REASON_ID":"1", "STATUS":"1", "NOTE":"1", "GET_FROM_STOCK_TRANS_ID" : "1", 
   "TRANSACTION_ACTION": [{"ACTION_CODE":"1", "TYPE": "1", "STATUS" : "1", "NOTE":"1", "USERNAME":"1", "ACTION_STAFF_ID":"1" }],
   "STOCK_TRANSACTION_DETAIL" : 
    [
    {"GOODS_ID":"1", "STATE_ID":"1", "QUANTITY":"1", "PRICE":"1", "NOTE":"1", "TYPE":"1", "GOODS_STATUS":"1", "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID":"1", 
    "STOCK_TRANSACTION_SERIAL": 
    [
     {"FROM_SERIAL":"1", "TO_SERIAL":"1", "QUANTITY":"1", "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID":"INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"}
     {"FROM_SERIAL":"1", "TO_SERIAL":"1", "QUANTITY":"1", "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID":"INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"}
    ]}

    {"GOODS_ID":"1", "STATE_ID":"1", "QUANTITY":"1", "PRICE":"1", "NOTE":"1", "TYPE":"1", "GOODS_STATUS":"1", "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID":"1", 
    "STOCK_TRANSACTION_SERIAL": 
    [
     {"FROM_SERIAL":"1", "TO_SERIAL":"1", "QUANTITY":"1", "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID":"INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"}
     {"FROM_SERIAL":"1", "TO_SERIAL":"1", "QUANTITY":"1", "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID":"INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"}
    ]}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for existing related questions?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: you can use JSONArray object for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019131/read-json-file-and-display-its-contents/21019227#21019227

Comment: Answer to this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Comment: The JSON you show is not valid JSON. You can check this via [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/). Once you have valid JSON, choose a Java JSON parsing library, and parse it.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
var foo =  {
     "STOCK_TRANSACTION": [{
         "STOCK_ID": "1",
         "DELIVERER_STOCK_ID": "1",
         "TYPE ": "1",
         "REASON_ID": "1",
         "STATUS": "1",
         "NOTE": "1",
         "GET_FROM_STOCK_TRANS_ID": "1",
         "TRANSACTION_ACTION": [{
             "ACTION_CODE": "1",
             "TYPE": "1",
             "STATUS": "1",
             "NOTE": "1",
             "USERNAME": "1",
             "ACTION_STAFF_ID": "1"
         }],
         "STOCK_TRANSACTION_DETAIL": [{
                 "GOODS_ID": "1",
                 "STATE_ID": "1",
                 "QUANTITY": "1",
                 "PRICE": "1",
                 "NOTE": "1",
                 "TYPE": "1",
                 "GOODS_STATUS": "1",
                 "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID": "1",
                 "STOCK_TRANSACTION_SERIAL": [{
                     "FROM_SERIAL": "1",
                     "TO_SERIAL": "1",
                     "QUANTITY": "1",
                     "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID": "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"
                 }, {
                     "FROM_SERIAL": "1",
                     "TO_SERIAL": "1",
                     "QUANTITY": "1",
                     "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID": "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"
                 }]
             },

             {
                 "GOODS_ID": "1",
                 "STATE_ID": "1",
                 "QUANTITY": "1",
                 "PRICE": "1",
                 "NOTE": "1",
                 "TYPE": "1",
                 "GOODS_STATUS": "1",
                 "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID": "1",
                 "STOCK_TRANSACTION_SERIAL": [{
                     "FROM_SERIAL": "1",
                     "TO_SERIAL": "1",
                     "QUANTITY": "1",
                     "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID": "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"
                 }, {
                     "FROM_SERIAL": "1",
                     "TO_SERIAL": "1",
                     "QUANTITY": "1",
                     "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID": "INTERNAL_STOCK_ID"
                 }]
             }
         ]
     }]
 }
```

Comment: what is this about ? Please read through the lines. He has asked how to map JSON to Java !