# Couldn't able to extract attributes present in JSON Array

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON in this format

```
{
    "futLink": "/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INFY&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=24APR2014&type=-&strike=-",
    "otherSeries": [
        "EQ"
    ],
    "lastUpdateTime": "01-APR-2014 16:00:01",
    "tradedDate": "01APR2014",
    "data": [
        {
            "deliveryToTradedQuantity": "66.31",
            "totalTradedVolume": "10,78,544"
        }
    ],
    "optLink": "/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=INFY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2"
}
```

I need to extract attributes present from  the section data array shown above

I tried using simple JSON Api

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(jsonString);
        System.out.println("tradedDate=" + json.get("tradedDate"));
        System.out.println("totalTradedVolume=" + json.get("totalTradedVolume"));
```

The output ia m getting is

**

```
tradedDate=01APR2014
totalTradedVolume=null
```

**

The issue i am facing is that , getting null value for the array section attributes

could anybody please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: can you try using jackson? or you need to stick to JSON API?

Comment: your answer is in accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019131/read-json-file-and-display-its-contents/21019227#21019227 ..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key `data` actually contains `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`s, so at first you should get the needed item, then get the value at the key. Replace this:

```
json.get("totalTradedVolume")
```

with this:

```
json.getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(0).getString("totalTradedVolume")
```

Please note, that your example contains only one item in `JSONArray`, but if you have multiple items inside it, you may want to iterate over them.

Comment: The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject , what api are you using ??

Comment: @PreethiJain what lib are you using for parsing JSON? My example is using `org.json`

Comment: @PreethiJain ok, looks like you are using `javax.json`. I've corrected my example to fit this lib

Comment: I am using org.json.simple . , the error still exists

Comment: Thanks , i could able to resovle this now  thank you very much once again .

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's connected with "data" (type of ARRAY). Try firstly retrieving "data" object and iterate over it to get "totalTradedVolume"

Answer (score 1):

You are getting totalTradedVolume as null because it is not a straight node in your response. It is present under array "data". So first get the response in JSONObject as you are doing. then extract the array as

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resp);
    System.out.println(object.get("futLink"));
    JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(o.get("deliveryToTradedQuantity"));
        System.out.println(o.get("totalTradedVolume"));
    }
```

Then try to get the underlying nodes.